# I have a vba code and I want to know the structure of the Excel file (the sheets) on which it is run

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have a problem to solve by vba, I find a code that does this task on the internet but I could not understand it, because I do not have the Excel file on which it is run. so my goal is to know the structure of the Excel file (sheets and columns), and especially I do not understand this part:

```
With Worksheets ("Output of PV")
     .Range (.Range ("_ pv") ....
```

I say that `_pv` is the name of a range, but I can not find in the code where is it defined?

My problem is with formula `range ("_ pv")`, and `range ("_ data")`

```
With  Worksheets("Sortie de PV")
  .Range(.Range("_pv").Offset(0, 0), .Range("_pv").Offset(10000, 100)).Value = ""
EntWith
```

Comment: `.Range(.Range` is extremely suspicious. and `.Offset(0, 0)` is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

The Named Range `_pv` is NOT defined in VBA. It's defined in the Excel Name Manager. You can find the `Name Manager` in the "Formula" tab of the ribbon.

[image]

As for the rest of this code:

1. `With Worksheets("Sortie de PV")` is saying: When you encounter, in the lines before the `End With` an object, method, or parameter preceded with a `.`, I am referring to this worksheet.
2. On that worksheet SET the `.Value` of the `Range()` where the Row is from first cell in the named range `"_pv"` and the Column is 10000 rows down and 100 columns over from the named range `"_pv"`

That second one is a little clunky and could probably just be reduced to something like `.Range("_pv").Resize(100, 10000).ClearContents`. Also because there is only a single line in that `With` block, then the `With` really isn't necessary. So this whole thing could probably just be:

```
Worksheeets("Sortie de PV").Range("_pv").Resize(100, 10000).ClearContents
```

If that doesn't work exactly, then referring to the first cell in the `"_pv"` named range might be better:

```
Worksheets("Sortie de PV").Range("_pv").Cells(1,1).Resize(100, 10000).ClearContents
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr @JNevill